# Image Taking Full Width Of Container

Tags: html, css

really basic question, but I do marketing for a client so don't know too much besides basics HTML, CSS.

I've got an image slider in the URL below, what should I do so the image occupies the full space of the container (as there are bars on either side of the image). Do I just remove the padding or is there something more efficient to put in the stylesheet. Thanks heaps for your help

https://www.vibrantrealestate.com.au/property/outstanding-warehouse-space-style-on-the-citys-edge/

[image]

Comment: [so] is a website for [professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is intended at helping you become a better programmer, should you ever chose to become one. It's not intended at providing free programming services. Read [ask] on how you can ask a good question here and make sure you update your question with your research and your best coding attempt.

Comment: hey andrei, that's fair enough. i'll make sure to ask a more relevant question that i've tested out aswell beforehand next time. apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this rule in your CSS file :

```
.inspiry_property_portrait_slider .flex-viewport ul li a img{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css

```css
div
{
background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this just because I'm pretty sure a guy with 5k rep knows what would be considered a useful answer. Though, I believe it was downvoted because you didn't explain that background-size:cover is what allows the image to fill the space entirely. Still, this could - in theory - solve the OP's issue